# How to pull Data into python from SAP ERP

Tags: python, sap-erp, sap-bw

I am a data scientist and do not have any prior background in SAP.

I need to pull data (query and Qube) from SAP ERP to python for some predictions and automate the process. but I am not able to find the right answer to this.
our SAP ERP runs on the Oracle database but I don't have access to pull data directly from oracle,
also we have SAP BW.
Please help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with tutorials like this [one](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/09/connecting-python-with-sap-step-by-step-guide/).
After that you can ask more specific question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data using various ways, or using different Data Ingestion tools.
It would also depend upon multiple factors but naming a few

- On-premise or Cloud(AWS, Azure, GCP)
- Whether you want to get data only once or on daily basis.

I am assuming you want to get data only once and your DB connectivity is working fine. Install these, if they are not

```
pip install pandas
pip install SQLAlchemy
pip install cx_Oracle
```

In your python notebook or IDE

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy
```

Add appropriate values of (user, password, hostIP:Port , service_name) in engine.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@hostIP:port/service_name=DB_name", arraysize=1000)
SQL_query = """SELECT* from table"""
df = pd.read_sql(SQL_query, engine)
```

Comment: I want the data on a daily basis, and I do not have query access to the database, I can only access the data via sap